# Polymer paper-tabs with core pages scroll height stays the same

Tags: polymer

I have a page with 3 tabs and each tab has different height of content. On mobile devices if i scroll half way on the first tab, if I switch too the second tab my scroll bar will be in the middle content on my page. I was wondering is it possible to make the top content display when I switch between tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine question. I think, preserving an original scrollTop position must be default behavior in Polymer. The problem is in single scrollable container, like *core-header-panel*. There are no multiple containers for each *core-page*. Switching the tabs just hides and shows page containers.

There are some guys from Polymer team, it will be interesting to hear their opinion on this solution:

```
var panel = document.querySelector('core-header-panel');
var core_pages = document.querySelector('core-pages');
var scrollable;

panel.onscroll = function(event) {
  scrollable = event.detail.target;
  var scrollTop = (scrollable.scrollTop || 0);
  var selectedIndex = (core_pages.selectedIndex < 0 ? 0 : core_pages.selectedIndex);
  document.querySelectorAll('paper-tab')[selectedIndex].pos = scrollTop;
}

var tabs = document.getElementById('tabs');
tabs.addEventListener('core-activate', function(event) {
  scrollable.scrollTop = (event.detail.item.pos || 0);
});
```

Comment: Do you simplified it to scroll tabs to top on enter or there are some bugs found? I've tested it before answering